# VSCode - intellisense ignores headers injected using clang.cxxflags

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

For various ugly reasons I won't go into here, I need to use the -include compiler flag to inject a header file before compilation. VSCode (Version 1.14.2, running on Ubuntu) does not seem to scan headers injected this way. I have tried adding the option and path to settings.json (clang.cxxflags), but no luck.

Here's the question:

Is there another way to get Intellisense to scan a header without including that header directly in the source file? I've looked at c_cpp_properties.json and see where to add header search paths, but no way to inject specific headers. Obviously, including the header explicitly fixes Intellisense for the file, but that is not an option.

Any feedback is appreciated.